# Question marks instead of national letters in console

Tags: ls, locale, character-encoding, mc

I have [Netgear Stora MS2000](http://support.netgear.com/product/MS2000) (which uses a modified version of Red Hat) and have strange font issues while connecting by SSH. Note that this occurs both when connecting by PuTTY from Windows and by performing `ssh` from Mac console.

When I use some Polish letter and type `ls` it is displayed as two question marks. However, when I try to autocomplete the file name it displays correctly. This is illustrated in the following picture:

[image: console example]

Tried to change `TERM` and `LANG` variables to different values but without any luck.

I also noticed wrong display of `mc`, this may (or may not) be related to the same issue:

[image: mc]

Any ideas what should I change?

The screens where made from PuTTY but it looks the same from Mac terminal.

**EDIT**

Answering question from comment, here is output from `locale`, `alias ls` and `echo młodość | od -t x1`:

```
-bash-3.2$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
-bash-3.2$ alias ls
alias ls='ls --color=tty'
-bash-3.2$ echo młodość | od -t x1
0000000 6d c5 82 6f 64 6f c5 9b c4 87 0a
0000013
-bash-3.2$
```

Comment: What is the output of `locale`, of `alias ls`, and of `echo młodość | od -t x1`?

Comment: @Gilles: See updated question.

Comment: Given the messages from `locale`, I think the locale definition files for your language are missing. Either you need some command to install them manually ([this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/International_Language_Support_Guide/Installing_and_supporting_languages-Adding_language_support_after_installation.html) is the GUI way, I don't know what the command line way is) or the files have been omitted from this stripped-down installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment from Gilles I managed to fix this issue. The problem was missing pl_PL locale. I found instructions on [PC LOAD LETTER blog](http://pcloadletter.co.uk/2011/02/07/serviio-on-synology-nas-with-arm-cpu/):

```bsh
cd ~/sometemp
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/dsgpl/files/DSM%203.1%20Tool%20Chains/Marvell%2088F628x%20Linux%202.6.32/gcc421_glibc25_88f628x.tgz
tar xvfz gcc421_glibc25_88f628x.tgz
cd arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/bin
cp locale /opt/bin
cp localedef /opt/bin
cp -R arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/share/i18n /usr/share
#-----keep another copy safe in case DSM is reinstalled later
cp -R arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/share/i18n /opt/share
mkdir /usr/lib/locale
```

And then by typing:

```bsh
localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i pl_PL pl_PL.utf8
```

and relogging everything works.